React: Empty Array Displayed Before Asynchronous Data Fetched (Search Functionality)
I'm facing an issue with my React application's search functionality. When I submits a search term, the application initially displays an empty list of recipes. Yet by using console.log on my backend I quickly realize that it instantly sends the empty array yet after a while it correctly fetches the data im interested in... Since Its my first time practicing using APIs that are not locally hosted(I'm fetching information from spoonacular). I am not sure If I need to change something from my code:
This is my Backend APIs:
// recipe-api

export const searchRecipes = async (searchTerm:string,page:number)=>{
if (!apiKey) {
throw new Error("API Key not found");
}
const url = new URL("https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch");

const queryParams = {
    apiKey: apiKey,
    query: searchTerm,
    number: "10",
    offset: (page * 10).toString(),
}

url.search = new URLSearchParams(queryParams).toString();

try {
    const searchResponse  = await fetch(url);
    console.log(searchResponse)
    const resultsJson = await searchResponse.json();
    return resultsJson;
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
} }


My frontend api:
//api-client

export const searchRecipes = async(search:string, page: number)=>{
const baseURL = new URL("http://localhost:3000/api/recipes/search");
baseURL.searchParams.append("searchTerms",search);
baseURL.searchParams.append("page",page.toString());

console.log(baseURL);
const response = await fetch(baseURL);

if(!response.ok){
    throw new Error(`Something went wrong.... ${response.status}`);
}

return response.json(); }


The submit handler and the element that its beeing called upon
//Handler

const [search, setSearchTerm] = useState("burgers");   const
[recipes, setRecipes] = useState<Recipe[]>([]);
const handleSearchSubmit = async (event: FormEvent)
=> {
event.preventDefault();
try {
  const recipesFound = await api.searchRecipes(search, 1);
  console.log(recipesFound);
  setRecipes(recipesFound.results);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}   };


// Element thats invoking the handler

 
      
        Submit
      
      {recipes.map((recipe: Recipe) => (
        
          recipe image location: {recipe.image}
          recipe title: {recipe.title}
        
      ))}
    

I'm fairly new to React, hooks and fetching. So any feedback is appreciated.
